# How to successfully match Failure mappings between two Publishers (Never and URLError)

Tags: combine

After scouring a few different resources on Combine, including Joseph Heck and Donny Wals's books, I'm close to understanding chaining of DataTaskPublishers but failing in connecting them together into one series of chained operators.  I seem to be getting hung up on the fact that the errors between the output of the first publisher doesn't match the expected input of the second.  Both Publisher extensions work when not connected, so I am sure it is a lack of ability in joining the two.  I would have thought mapError() would have worked but it does not want to compile.

Here's the setup:

Given two custom publishers:

```
extension Publisher where Output == MKCoordinateRegion, Failure == URLError {

func toRegionDataTask() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, URLError> {
    return self
        .flatMap({ region -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher in
                  ...
                  ... 
                  ...
                  return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)       
                  })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

and

```
extension Publisher where Output == [String], Failure == Never {

func toGeographiesDataTask() ->  AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, URLError {
    return self
        .setFailureType(to: URLError.self)
        .flatMap({ ids -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher in
                   ...
                   ...
                   ...
                  return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                 })
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

}

I then have a function that tries to chain the two together like so:

```
   let passthroughSubj = PassthroughSubject<MKCoordinateRegion,URLError>()

    passthroughSubj
    .toRegionDataTask()                                         // returns <DataTaskPublisher, URLError>
    .map { $0.data }                                            // returns <FlatMap, ?>
    .decode(type: ApiResponse.self, decoder:JSONDecoder())      // returns <ApiResonse, ?>
    .map {$0.body.data(using: .utf8)! }                         // returns <Data, ?>
    .decode(type: AmznResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())    // returns <AmznResponse, ?>
    .map ({ response -> [AmznItem] in                           //
                return response.contents                        // returns <[AmznItem], ?>
    })
    .map ({ items -> [String] in                                // returns <[String], Never> ?
            var ids = [String]()
            for item in items {
                    ids.append(item.geoid)
            }
            return ids
            })
//
//        .toGeographiesDataTask()                                  // get error "Referencing instance method
//        .map { $0.data }                                          // 'toGeographiesDataTask()' on 'Publisher'
//        .decode(type: ApiResponse.self, decoder:JSONDecoder())    // requires the types 'Error' and 'Never'
//        .map {$0.body.data(using: .utf8)! }                       // be equivalent"
//        .decode(type: AmznResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
//        .map { $0.contents }
//
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .finished:
            print("DONE")
        }
        }, receiveValue: { data in
           print(data)
        })
    .store(in: &cancellables)

passthroughSubj.send(region1)
```

If I uncomment the second custom publisher, I get the error message shown on the right.  My understanding was that the .map was returning <[String],Never> but eventually because the DataTaskPublisher could fail I need to map it to URLError instead.  But no combination of .mapError seems to compile either.

Am I missing something fundamental here?  Seems like an easy problem to fix but I'm not finding anything sticking out.

I have seen examples where you use .flatMap to chain these together but since I am transforming the output of one into an input for the second custom publisher that didn't seem possible.

Any help or pointers would be very welcome!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have some decodable types that we'll need to mock in order to play around:

```
struct ApiResponse: Decodable {
    var body: String
}

// Does the abbreviation "Amzn" really improve the program?
struct AmazonResponse: Decodable {
    var contents: [AmazonItem]
}

struct AmazonItem: Decodable {
    var geoid: String
}
```

Then you have a couple of custom `Publisher` operators, each of which needs to create a `URLRequest`. Let's reduce nesting and let Swift infer more types by factoring out that code:

```
func apiRequest(for region: MKCoordinateRegion) -> URLRequest {
    // Your code here. fatalError gets this through the compiler.
    fatalError()
}

func geographiesRequest(forIds ids: [String]) -> URLRequest {
    // Your code here. fatalError gets this through the compiler.
    fatalError()
}
```

Now let's look at your first custom operator, `toRegionDataTask`.

- You've defined it only for publishers where `Failure == URLError`. Maybe that's what you really want, but since we're going to be decoding downstream anyway, and decoding has a `Failure` type of `Error`, let's just use `Error` throughout.
- You've had to manually specify the `Publisher` type returned by the `flatMap` transform. Since we factored out `apiRequest(for:)`, we no longer need to do that.

So we could try this:

```
extension Publisher where Output == MKCoordinateRegion {
    func toRegionDataTask() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> {
        return self
            .map { apiRequest(for: $0) }
            .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

But woe unto us, for the compiler has complaints:

> error: Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:31:18: error: instance method
>   'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' requires the types 'Self.Failure' and
>   'URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure' (aka 'URLError') be equivalent
>
> ```
>             .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0) }
>              ^
> ```
>
> error: Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:32:18: error: cannot convert
>   return expression of type
>   'AnyPublisher' (aka
>   'AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Self.Failure>') to
>   return type 'AnyPublisher'
>   (aka 'AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Error>')
>
> ```
>             .eraseToAnyPublisher()
>              ^
> ```
>
> Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:32:18: note: arguments to generic
>   parameter 'Failure' ('Self.Failure' and 'Error') are expected to be
>   equal
>
> ```
>             .eraseToAnyPublisher()
>              ^
> ```

The way to debug this is to break it up into multiple steps, and use `eraseToAnyPublisher` after each step to see the `Output` and `Failure` types:

```
    func toRegionDataTask() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> {
        let x = self
            .map { apiRequest(for: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        let y = x
            .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        return y
    }
```

Now we can see (by option-clicking `x`) that after the `map`, `Output` is `URLRequest` and `Failure` is `Self.Failure`—whatever failure type `self` produces. This makes sense because I removed the constraint `Failure == URLError` from the extension.

The compiler now just emits the first of the prior complaints:

> error: Untitled Page.xcplaygroundpage:34:18: error: instance method 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)' requires the types 'Self.Failure' and 'URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure' (aka 'URLError') be equivalent

This says that the “input” `Failure` type to the `flatMap` operator has to be the same as the “output” `Failure` type. The input type is `Self.Failure` and the output is `URLError`. This is probably why you had constrained `Failure == URLError` on the extension. But I prefer to solve it differently, by converting both failure types to `Error` using `mapError`. This makes it easier to write tests for the method, and to change how it's used in the future. Here's what I would do:

```
extension Publisher where Output == MKCoordinateRegion {
    func toRegionDataTask() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> {
        let x = self
            .map { apiRequest(for: $0) }
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        let y = x
            .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0).mapError { $0 as Error } }
                                                                 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()

        return y
    }
}
```

Finally we can remove the intermediate steps to get the final version:

```
extension Publisher where Output == MKCoordinateRegion {
    func toRegionDataTask() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> {
        return self
            .map { apiRequest(for: $0) }
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0).mapError { $0 as Error } }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

We'll give `toGeographiesDataTask` the same treatment:

```
extension Publisher where Output == [String] {
    func toGeographiesDataTask() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> {
        return self
            .map { geographiesRequest(forIds: $0) }
            .mapError { $0 as Error }
            .flatMap { URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0).mapError { $0 as Error } }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

You might notice that `toRegionDataTask` and `toGeographiesDataTask` are now nearly identical. But I'm going to leave that alone for this answer.

So anyway, now let's look at your long pipeline. You were getting an error because your `toGeographiesDataTask` had the constraint `Failure == Never`, but the `map` operator preceding it does **not** have a `Failure` type of `Never`. It has the same `Failure` type as its upstream, which is `Error` (because of the `decode(type:decoder:)` operator).

Since I removed that constraint from `toGeographiesDataTask`, the pipeline no longer has that error. We can clean up the extraction of `geoid` a little bit though:

```
// Does the abbeviation "subj" really improve the program?
// The subject's Failure type could be anything here.
let subject = PassthroughSubject<MKCoordinateRegion, Error>()

var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []

subject
    .toRegionDataTask()
    .map { $0.data }
    .decode(type: ApiResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .map { $0.body.data(using: .utf8)! }
    .decode(type: AmazonResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .map { $0.contents }
    .map { $0.map { $0.geoid } }
    .toGeographiesDataTask()
    .map { $0.data }
    .decode(type: ApiResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .map { $0.body.data(using: .utf8)! }
    .decode(type: AmazonResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .map { $0.contents }
    .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { print("completion: \($0)") },
        receiveValue: { print("value: \($0)") })
    .store(in: &tickets)

let region1 = MKCoordinateRegion()
subject.send(region1)
```

Comment: Lots of useful stuff to digest here!  The refactoring (and the walkthrough) is very helpful and helps explain Xcode's more obtuse error messaging.

The most immediate impact came from re-splitting the code (originally I was working on parts of the chain separately and it was working) and then using eraseToAnyPublisher() to make the Outputs and Failures more visible.

There is definitely an explainer on properly developing and recomposing operator chains in here that lots of people would find useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `map` operator only transforms the `Output`, it leaves the `Error` intact. So if I were to fill in the blanks on your `Output` and `Failure` pairs I would end up with this:

```
// returns <DataTaskPublisher, URLError>
// returns <Data, URLError>
// returns <ApiResonse, Error> (decode replaces the Failure with Error)
// returns <Data, Error>
// returns <AmznResponse, Error>
// returns <[AmznItem], Error>
// returns <[String], Error>
```

Your implementation of `toGeographiesDataTask` requires that the publisher it's applied to has `Never` as its error which is why you get the compiler error you're getting.

I think you can remove the error requirement from your extension and make it

```
extension Publisher where Output == [String] {
  // implementation
}
```

Then inside of `toGeographiesDataTask()` you can replace the `URLError` that's emitted by the data task using `mapError`:

```
func toGeographiesDataTask() ->  AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> {
    return self
        .flatMap({ ids -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output, Error> in
                   ...
                   ...
                   ...
                  return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
                    .mapError({ $0 as Error})
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                 })
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

I think this should get the rest of the chain to work too and you should end up with `<[AmznItem], Error>` as the `<Output, Failure>` at the end of the chain.

I haven't tried this in a Playground though but I'm fairly sure this should get you going.

Comment: I got this working after this, thanks - as I’m cleaning up the playground thought I would share what did and didn’t work as expected:

Stripping the "Failure==Error" ?predicate? from the definition of toGeographiesDataTask() didn’t work as expected — flatMap began to complain.  I am sure that mapError might help here as well, but I got it working without this step so I left it alone for the moment.

The correct mapping of Outputs and Failures was very helpful.  Wish Xcode made this more visible.

Comment: Followup - stripping the Failure predicate only didn't work because another failure type was declared further down into the operator chain.  It was great to have multiple answers to grok the process.